# SQL Server dynamic pivot as stored procedure using parameters

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, dynamic, parameters

I have been working to make a dynamic pivot in SQL Server that a user could call in a stored procedure and pass specified parameters  ie:

```
 exec piv(schema, table, agg_type, aggCol, newCol)
```

I am struggling to finish out the schema and table parameters.

Here is what I have so far:

```
BEGIN

DECLARE @Piv AS NVARCHAR(max)  --final pivot. print this to see the exec statement
DECLARE @NewColumns AS NVARCHAR(max) -- extract data and format to make new columns
DECLARE @COLUMNS AS NVARCHAR(MAX) -- list of all columns to be used for CTE below
DECLARE @PivColumns AS NVARCHAR(MAX) --list of all columns except the 2 columns involved in pivot

--declaring parameters here for now

declare @aggCol nvarchar(max)
declare @newCol nvarchar(max)
declare @table nvarchar(max)
declare @schm nvarchar(max)

--To be used for parameters in the SP

set @schm = 'dbo'
set @table = 'Report'
set @aggCol = 'Flag'
set @newCol = 'Category'

-- extracts data and formats for new columns... here is where I'm stuck.
-- I have tried every way I can find to pass the variables in this statement and no luck

SELECT @NewColumns = COALESCE(@NewColumns + ',','') +   QUOTENAME(CATEGORY) + char(13)
FROM
(
SELECT DISTINCT Category  --needs to be dynamic ie: @newCol
FROM
dbo.Report  --needs to be dynamic ie: @table
) AS B


-- list of all columns to be used for CTE below

SELECT @Columns = COALESCE(@Columns + ',','') +   QUOTENAME(COLUMN_NAME) + char(13)
FROM
(
SELECT DISTINCT COLUMN_NAME
FROM
(
SELECT 
 SCHEMA_NAME(T.SCHEMA_ID) AS 'SCHEMA_NAME' -- GET THIS WORKING TO GET A SPECIFIC TABLE
,T.NAME AS 'TABLE_NAME'
,C.NAME AS 'COLUMN_NAME'
FROM SYS.COLUMNS C 
INNER JOIN SYS.TABLES T ON C.OBJECT_ID = T.OBJECT_ID
WHERE T.NAME = @table) AS A
) AS B
ORDER BY B.COLUMN_NAME


--list of all columns except the 2 columns involved in pivot

SELECT @PivColumns = 

COALESCE(@PivColumns + ',','') +   QUOTENAME(COLUMN_NAME) + char(13)
FROM
(
SELECT DISTINCT COLUMN_NAME
FROM
(
SELECT 
 SCHEMA_NAME(T.SCHEMA_ID) AS 'SCHEMA_NAME' -- GET THIS WORKING TO GET A SPECIFIC TABLE
,T.NAME AS 'TABLE_NAME'
,C.NAME AS 'COLUMN_NAME'
FROM SYS.COLUMNS C 
INNER JOIN SYS.TABLES T ON C.OBJECT_ID = T.OBJECT_ID
WHERE T.NAME = @table
and (C.name not like @aggCol or C.name not like @newCol)
) AS A
) AS B
ORDER BY B.COLUMN_NAME

--Removes columns that are used on the pivot

SET @PivColumns = REPLACE(REPLACE(@PivColumns,char(13)+',['+@aggcol+']',''),char(13)+',['+@newcol+']','')

--final statement to print/exec

SET @Piv ='
WITH T1 AS
(
SELECT 
'+@COLUMNS+'
FROM 
 '+@table+'
)

SELECT 
       '+@PivColumns+'
      ,'+@NewColumns+'
FROM T1
PIVOT
(MAX(FLAG) FOR CATEGORY IN ('+@NewColumns+'))AS PIV'

print(@Piv)
END
```

Feel free to add suggestions or edit in any way ie: tempTable, cte, etc...

I built this in another window that gets me what I need but I do not think I can use it in the first statement:

```
BEGIN

DECLARE @NewColumns AS NVARCHAR(max)
declare @newCol nvarchar(max)
declare @table nvarchar(max)

set @newCol = 'Category'
set @table = '[dbo].[REPORT]'
Select @NewColumns = 
'
DECLARE @NewColumns AS NVARCHAR(max)
declare @table nvarchar(max)

SELECT @NewColumns = COALESCE(@NewColumns + '','','''') +   QUOTENAME(CATEGORY) + char(13)

FROM
(
SELECT DISTINCT '+@newCol+'
FROM
'+@table+'
) AS B
print(@NewColumns)
'
exec(@NewColumns) 
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
    DECLARE @SQL VARCHAR(MAX)
    DECLARE @List VARCHAR(MAX)
    DECLARE @SQLList nVARCHAR(MAX)

    SET @SQLList=N'select @List=stuff((SELECT DISTINCT '',''+AccountType FROM '+@table+'. FOR XML PATH('''')),1,1,'''')'
    exec sp_executesql  @SQLList ,N'@List VARCHAR(MAX) out', @List out
    select @List
    SET @SQL=
    '
    SELECT * FROM (SELECT '+@newCol +','+@aggCol+'  
        FROM '+@table+') AS SourceTable
    PIVOT
    (
    '+@agg_type+'('+@aggCol+')
    FOR '+@newCol +'IN ('+@List+')
    ) AS PivotTable;'
  exec(@SQL)
```

Comment: I tried to plug all and parts of this in and cannot get it going :(